# In modern c#, is there a pattern for a struct to replace a long list of arguments?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, struct

So, I want to replace a long list of arguments with a struct.

My motivation (but not my question) is: I want to reduce the amount of arguments used to pass this exact data around, without having to introduce a new object to the garbage collector.

So my idea is that i create a **ref** struct, and pass that on. The struct will be passed to methods that use the 'in' keyword. And because every member is now readonly, no defensive copies of this struct will happen, and all the arguments will live at exactly one place in the memory stack, and be cleaned when they fall out of scope.

This seems to me like a good, general way to replace a long list of arguments. But I might be wrong, and the fear of "defensive copies" itches in the back of my mind.

Is there a good reference, or example I can follow, in case this was not it?

```
readonly ref struct MappingButtonData {
    readonly public AudioSourcePool       sourcePool            { get; }
    readonly public InputCollisionManager inputCollisionManager { get; }
    // ... etc
    readonly public string                hoverSound            { get; }

    public MappingButtonData ( /* each member's initial value */ ) {

        this.sourcePool            = sourcePool;
        this.inputCollisionManager = inputCollisionManager;
        // ... etc
        this.hoverSound            = hoverSound;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Even if you used a "normal" struct, only the struct would be copied around on the stack, but not the references it points to. Unless it is really huge, you shouldn't notice a big performance impact by this.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in c# with using a struct.  It is done all the time when sending objects to older c language programs.   It also saves memory.  The disadvantage of using struct is that it does not contain types so checking can not be done at runtime for mismatched types.